# Область видимости сессий в PHP

Tags: php, сессия

На моем сайте, если выводить значение переменной в сессии, наприме:

```
echo $_SESSION["key];
```

то со скрипта `index.php` все видит, а если обратится к этой же переменной из другого скрипта находящийся во вложенной директории, то выводит пустое значение. С чем это связано? Или я не совсем понял области видимости сессий.

```
/*index.php*/
...
echo $_SESSION["key"];// 1234567890
```

и

```
/*mydir/msg.php*/
echo $_SESSION["key"];// пусто!!!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.session.php) - суперглобальная переменная. Чтобы получить к ней доступ, нужно вызвать  [session_start](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php)();

Comment: да не было старта сессий...

Answer (score 1):

Функция [session_start();](http://www.php.su/functions/?session-start) присутствует в обоих скриптах?