# Долгий ответ сервера

Tags: php, сессия

В продолжении [темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/130709/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-php), когда стартую сессии сервер на запросы отвечает очень долго (минут 5!). Как это исправить или в чем косяк?

Если не стартовать сессии, то все в порядке.

Comment: Было бы полезным узнать что за CMS и ОС..

Comment: Где сохраняются сессии: на диске, в БД, в memcached? Измерьте время выполнения именно строки `session_start()` запомнив время до и сразу после неё типа

    $before = microtime( TRUE);
    session_start();
    echo ( 'Старт сессии занял ' . (microtime( TRUE) - $before) . 'ms. ';

Покажет в 1/1000 секунд, сколько времени именно сессия стартовала. А то, может, в другом месте затык?

Comment: CMS самописный. ОС - фри. Время выполнения session_start() - 211.059983015ms

Где хранятся сессии не имею понятия. В системе я не шарю. У меня стоит стандартный ДиректАдмин, без каких либо особых настроек.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь методом мозгового штурма надо думать )

Вот первое что пришло в голову - отсутствует место на диске. Когда php стартует сессию, в папке /tmp создается файл сессии. Глянь, может быть места нет, а минут через 5 появляется свободное место и сессия создается..